# How do we concatenate all files in Linux excluding the directories?

Tags: linux

I am trying to get the total number of lines in all files in a directory.

I tried to do the following:

```
cat * | wc -1
```

to get the total number of lines in the directory, but it gives me a message that some of the files are directories. ('cat : some_dir: Is a directory')

How can I exclude directories when concatenating all files?

Comment: Something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} \;`? Or you can just ignore the message. It is written to stderr and you need stdout.

Comment: Just ignore the error messages or redirect them into `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get just sum you can try something like below, get count of each file and sum it

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

add `-maxdepth 1` which skips scanning further

`-type f` for filtering only files

**Here is test results :**

```
$ seq 1 4 >file1

$ seq 1 5 >file2

$ cat file1
1
2
3
4

$ cat file2
1
2
3
4
5



$ find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \;
5 ./file2
4 ./file1

$ find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
9

$ find . -type f -exec wc -l {} +
 5 ./file2
 4 ./file1
 9 total

$ find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | awk 'END{print $1}'
9
```

Answer (score 0):

### Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*
```

From bash's man page:

> ```
> globstar
>      If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
>      text  will  match all files and zero or more directories
>      and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a  /,
>      only directories and subdirectories match.
> ```

But care: this will take symlinks too!

### Some tricks about `find`

If you want to read *files* only:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

and, for total only:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | tail -n 1
```

#### Huge dirs:

Syntax `find ... -exec ... +` will limit groupping args to maximum line length. So if your tree is really big, the previous command will generate more than only one fork to `wc`.

> ```
> -exec command {} +
>       This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>       the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>       each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
>       tions of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of
>       matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
>       that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
>       is  allowed  within the command, and (when find is being invoked
>       from a shell) it should be quoted (for example, '{}') to protect
>       it  from  interpretation  by shells.  The command is executed in
>       the starting directory.  If any invocation  returns  a  non-zero
>       value  as exit status, then find returns a non-zero exit status.
>       If find encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immedi‐
>       ate  exit, so some pending commands may not be run at all.  This
>       variant of -exec always returns true.
> ```

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + |  awk 'BEGIN{t=0};/total/{t+=$1};END{print t}'
```

This will compute sum of *total* lines.

#### Alternative: using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) for summarize

For fun, as there is no real improvment:

```
tot=0
while read val nam;do
    [ "$nam" = "total" ] && ((tot+=val))
  done < <( find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + )
echo $tot
```

Comment: It was not downvoted. Just the upvote has been reverted. It was me, because I think at the end that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047622/how-do-we-concatenate-all-files-in-linux-excluding-the-directories#comment79054861_46047622) piped to `wc -l` is just perfect.

Comment: Also please read my note about `find .. -exec -- +` syntax: `find . -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l` will be quicker than using `\;` syntax as second one will generate one fork to `cat` by file.

Comment: ... and with `shopt -s globstar` , syntax could be `cat **/*|wc -l` or `wc -l < <(cat **/*)`

Comment: I see the point of `{} +` instead of `{} \;` but that's just a detail. At the end the approach of catting the file with `find` and use `wc -l` afterwards is perfect. About the globstar thingy, yeah it's nice but not POSIX.

Comment: @hek2mgl It's not a ***detail***: Running `cat` as many time there is files, is not same footprint than runing `cat` only once with all files as arguments....

Comment: This is not new to me and I always, if applicable, use it. The point is that it is better to run `cat` in the exec option than `wc`. Btw, I did not downvoted it and I'm asking myself why it has been downvoted.